# Swift: Bound value in a conditional binding must be optional

Tags: xcode, swift, types, conditional-statements, option-type

I am getting an error on this line of code:

```
if let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
```

The full code is below. It was working in previous version of Swift but for some reason getting compile error now.  Any ideas what the issue is?

```
class func logInWithFacebook() {
PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(["public_profile"], block: {
    (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if user == nil {
        NSLog("The user cancelled the Facebook login (user is nil)")
    } else {
        NSLog("The user successfully logged in with Facebook (user is NOT nil)")

        if let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation() { // ERROR
            let acl = PFACL(user: PFUser.currentUser()!) // 
            acl.setPublicReadAccess(true) 
            acl.setWriteAccess(true, forRoleWithName: "Admin") 
            installation.ACL = acl
            installation.saveEventually()
        }
        // THEN I GET THE USERNAME AND fbId
        Utils.obtainUserNameAndFbId()
    }
})
}
```

Comment: Do code for `else` part...and tell us what happens?

Answer (score 0):

It means that that the return type of `PFInstallation.currentInstallation()` must be an optional, if it's being unwrapped in the line with the `if let` declaration.

Right now, that call returns a `PFInstallation` Object (not `PFInstallation?`, an `Optional(PFInstallation)`). If this was working "before", maybe you mean before swift 1.2 that introduced some changes to the Objective C interoperabilit.

See the documentation at https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFInstallation.html#//api/name/currentInstallation

To correct your code, remove the `if let` line:

```
class func logInWithFacebook() {
    PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(["public_profile"], block: {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if user == nil {
            NSLog("The user cancelled the Facebook login (user is nil)")
        } else {
            NSLog("The user successfully logged in with Facebook (user is NOT nil)")


            let acl = PFACL(user: PFUser.currentUser()!) // 
            acl.setPublicReadAccess(true) 
            acl.setWriteAccess(true, forRoleWithName: "Admin") 
            installation.ACL = acl
            installation.saveEventually()

            // THEN I GET THE USERNAME AND fbId
            Utils.obtainUserNameAndFbId()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: If it was working before, it's not because of interoperability changes in Swift/Objective-C, but instead it's because the library the asker is using got updated to using the `nonnull` nullability annotation, rather than no annotation or the `nullable` annotation.

Comment: Yes, the Objective C code was updated but I believe that the ability to work with those annotations are also part of the changes with swift 1.2 see : http://nshipster.com/swift-1.2/